# Library for dragging elements from a palette to a HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Wondering if anybody has heard about a JavaScript library which allows to drag elements  (simple base graphs of different shape, which can be connected to each other) from a custom defined palette onto a (HTML5) canvas?

In the optimal case it would be possible to use SVG vector graphics to populate the palette.

On the one hand-side [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) seems to be too low-level (but very nice for drawing purposes) and on the other hand-side [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) too specific for arranging SVG objects on the canvas.

Comment: What's "too specific" about Fabric?

Comment: Seems like fabric concentrates with drawing and manipulating SVG objects on the canvas, for my purposes a palette concept interacting with the canvas is missing.

Comment: Do you mean "dragging onto canvas" concept? Yeah, that's not implemented natively in fabric, although I've seen few demos where folks implement it via any other drag-drop-supporting library.

Comment: Alright (yes: dragging onto canvas), but may be there are other interesting libraries, and which "drag-and-drop-supporting library" do you think of..., thx

Comment: For example, draggable module from jQueryUI. Once you drag something onto canvas, just remove draggable element and create its representation on canvas.